# Variation in Young's Modulus of Elasticity with Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, elasticity, physical-constants

[deleted] @ 5th July .................

Comment: What do you think are the relevant equations?

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is $p=mv$ with $p$ constant, call it $c$. So you you can write $v=c/m$. Kinetic energy then becomes $T=\frac{1}{2} m \left(\frac{c}{m}\right)^2= \frac{1}{2}\frac{c^2}{m}$. So $T\sim m^{-1}$.